# DatePicker SelectionChanged Code is not working - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls, datepicker

Here is my code in WPF:
XAML:

```
<StackPanel Width="150">
    <DatePicker Name="dpick" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" SelectedDateFormat="Short"/>
    <TextBlock Name="dpText"/>
</StackPanel>
```

C# Code:

```
public void dpick_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dpText.Text = dpick.SelectedDate.Value.Year.ToString() + "-" +
            dpick.SelectedDate.Value.Month.ToString() + "-" +
            dpick.SelectedDate.Value.Day.ToString();
}
```

dpText.Text is not updated after making a change in date.
Why this is happening.
I have tried with ValueChanged event also.Still no update is happening.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not using any of the events on the date picker. Try to add the SelectedDateChanged to the picker, and put your code from dpick_SelectionChanged in the newly created event instead.

```
<StackPanel Width="150">
    <DatePicker Name="dpick"  FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" SelectedDateFormat="Short"
                SelectedDateChanged="dpick_SelectedDateChanged"/>
    <TextBlock Name="dpText"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code:

```
private void dpick_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    dpText.Text = dpick.SelectedDate.Value.Year.ToString() + "-" +
        dpick.SelectedDate.Value.Month.ToString() + "-" +
        dpick.SelectedDate.Value.Day.ToString();
}
```

Comment: you can use string format instead of concatenating `dpDate.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`